# can I use Redux toolkit, while I'm also using React Context provider?

Tags: react-redux, react-context

I'm using React Context for authentication management from it I'm managing login activities but now I want to implement some other function so want to implement Redux toolkit for it,

Can I use both of them together in the same project or I need to remove the context provider to use redux